# iOS 8: Transition from UINavigationController to UISplitViewController, bad animation

Tags: ios, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, containment, uikit-transitions

I'm trying to animate a transition from a `UINavigationController` to a `UISplitViewController`, but the split view controller doesn't draw correctly until the animation is finished. The navigation bars are transparent and their titles are positioned wrong. When the animation finishes, they jump to the "correct" location. I'm using

`-transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion`

The `UISplitViewController` has `UINavigationController`s for both its master and detail. As it is transitioning in, the navigation bar is dark gray and the title is offset too high. Once the animation finishes, the bar quickly changes color to light gray and the title jumps into the correct place. Here's some example code:

```
// Master and its nav
UIViewController *master = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
master.title = @"master";
UINavigationController *masterNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master];
masterNav.toolbarHidden = NO;

// Detail and its nav
UIViewController *detail = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
detail.title = @"detail";
UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail];

// Split
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[ masterNav, detailNav ];

// Now transition
UIViewController *from = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];
[self addChildViewController:splitViewController];
NSTimeInterval duration = 1.0;
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve;
[self transitionFromViewController:from
                  toViewController:splitViewController
                          duration:duration
                           options:options
                        animations:^{}
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            [splitViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                        }];
```